# Partial border when displaying a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

On my page I have a content div that only shows when the mouse hovers over the sidebar div.

How do I remove only the border where the 2 divs touch like the picture below shows?

[image]

I need it to work in chrome, firefox & IE 8+

Here is a jsfiddle that sets up an example of my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/paulyoder/K2wKG/

For simplicity, please provide a jsfiddle of your solution

Comment: You asked the same question 3 days ago...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358134/partial-border-in-css

Comment: Could you use z-index to position the flyout behind the sidebar?

Comment: @novacara Yes, I asked a very similar question 3 days ago, but this one is different in that the content area is hidden and then shown during the hover

Comment: @Michelle I tried using z-index but I didn't have any luck with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare a background color of white for Side Bar

Declare a border-right: none; for Side Bar

then have side bar over lap Content by 1px this last step can be done may ways but I would need to see your specific markup.

Margin-left: -1px for content may do the trick!

Hope this helps

Here is a fiddle doing exactly as you describe. http://jsfiddle.net/3E4mD/1/

In the future it would be easier to see what you have and advise from there.

Thanks

Comment: Yea, that seems to work when the content area is always showing. In my case, I hide it and only display it when the mouse hovers over the side bar. When it's displayed, then the border is displayed

Comment: This is also how I would do it.

Comment: @Paul if post your markup I can assist further with hover events in the css, this is very doable.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what browsers your are supporting, you could use `:after` to add en element that would hide the black border by being positioned over it.

Like this : http://jsfiddle.net/htWzB/

Comment: Thanks for the Chrome & Firefox solution, but unfortunately I need to find a solution that works for IE 8+ as well, and IE 8 doesn't recognize :after