# Partial Border in CSS without background overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two divs with borders, how do I remove only the border where the 2 divs touch like the picture below shows? But without background overlapping, I mean here background must be transparent.
Question sounds seam like this one [Partial Border in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358134/partial-border-in-css) but!! without background color overlapping. and also it's liquid dimension, mean not fixed.

Comment: My answer will work with dynamic width. It just won't work with dynamic height.

Comment: yes, its valid answer for example what I provide because I sow this article what was close to my question, my bed is what i didn't ask for my case is horizontal menu with horizontal submenu like in this link https://www.mycleverphone.com/sergiu/Q/" . @ Joseph if u have some idea about dynamic width or height please post here same js example because i don't have idea yet how to do it. And i need this functionality in IE7.  Biggest Thanks.

Comment: try it again but without /" on final of link, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `div`s are both static height, you can use a pseudo element to fake the border:

```
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#small {
    border-right-width: 0;
    height: 80px;
}
#big {
    border-left-width: 0;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
#big:before {
    content: ' ';
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    height: 120px;
    left: 0; top: 80px;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FrKZy/

You could probably make it work with dynamic heights using Javascript.

---

**Warning:** this won't work in IE7 or under.